# SELECT for 2 columns from different status

Tags: sql, select

**I want to SELECT for 2 columns from two status**

```
ORDER_NUMBER | STATUS   | DATE
--------+-----------+--------------
001          | submit   | 2021-08-31 
113          | submit   | 2021-09-01
113          | approve  | 2021-09-03
001          | cancel   | 2021-09-02
112          | submit   | 2021-09-01
112          | cancel   | 2021-09-10
112          | resubmit | 2021-09-13
112          | approve  | 2021-09-15
```

**Expected result:**

```
ORDER_NUMBER | APPROVE_DATE | CANCEL_DATE
-------------+--------------+--------------
001          | null         | 2021-09-02
112          | 2021-09-15   | 2021-09-10
113          | 2021-09-03   | null
```

**My code:**

```
SELECT ORDER_NUMBER,
    CASE WHEN STATUS = 'approve' THEN DATE END AS APPROVE_DATE,
    CASE WHEN STATUS = 'cancel' THEN DATE END AS CANCEL_DATE
FROM 
    TABLE
```

**But the result it show**

```
ORDER_NUMBER | APPROVE_DATE | CANCEL_DATE
-------------+--------------+--------------
001          | null         | null
001          | null         | 2021-09-02
112          | null         | null
112          | null         | 2021-09-10
112          | null         | null
112          | 2021-09-15   | null
113          | null         | null 
113          | 2021-09-03   | null
```

**It shows duplicate ORDER NUMBER which not have my target status , How can I fix it?**

Comment: Please tag the correct dbms

Comment: Why do you select these pairs? For instance you show approve date 2021-08-31 next to cancel date 2021-09-04. Why? Are they somehow related? In SQL you show data that belongs together in one row. I don't see how the particular approve and cancel date pairs are related.

Comment: you need to explain your logic

Answer (score 0):

The main problem you're facing here is that there's absolutely no connections between your different entries inside the first table: you cannot tell which `approve` entry a given `cancel` entry corresponds to.

If what you actually want is classing an entry into the right column while preserving chronological order, you first need to sort your table according to this order, then specifying NULL in the other column:

```sql
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN STATUS = 'approve' THEN DATE ELSE NULL END AS APPROVE_DATE,
    CASE WHEN STATUS = 'cancel' THEN DATE ELSE NULL END AS CANCEL_DATE
FROM 
    TABLE
ORDER BY
    DATE ASC
```

…which will give you:

| APPROVE | CANCEL |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-08-31 | NULL |
| 2021-09-03 | NULL |
| NULL | 2021-09-04 |
| NULL | 2021-09-06 |
| 2021-09-09 | NULL |
| NULL | 2021-09-20 |

Also, `DATE` is a reserved keyword, so you'd better choose another name for you column. This will save you later troubles. ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have edited my information Can you help me again?

Answer (score 0):

Must be an ID in there somewhere to match off the approvals with the cancels? The logic below will show the approval date followed by the next earliest cancel.  So doesn't match your 2nd row, but you get the idea.

```
      select a.date Approve_date,
      c.Date Cancel_date
      from Status a
      left join Status c
      on c.order_number = a.order_number
      and c.status = 'cancel'
      where a.status = 'approve'
      order by  a.date
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have edited my information Can you help me again?

Comment: @Karina See edit

Answer (score 0):

Now you have edited your question, you now have an "order number" which is the actual ID of each entity you have stored attributes in your table.

So what you want to do now is first selecting all of these numbers, then pick "approve" and "cancel" dates for each of them. You typically want to do that with "**joins**". The trick here being the fact that you're totally allowed to perform a self-join, against the same table. So something like the following would do:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.order_number,
    t2.status AS Approval_Date,
    […] AS Cancel_Date

FROM table t1

LEFT OUTER JOIN table t2
ON t2.order_number = t1.order_number
AND t2.status = 'approve'

[…]

ORDER BY
    order_number ASC
```

Since this is possibly a homework, I'll let you complete this query by yourself. You just need to add another "LEFT OUTER JOIN" block like the one described here and complete SELECT statement for "Cancel_Date" row. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have updated your request. Now you simply want to select all orders in the table and for each show the approve and cancel date. The straight forward way to achieve this is to aggregate per order and fetch the names in the process. Aggregating values based on conditions is called conditional aggregation.

Your own query is very close. If you look at your result, you see that this is just an intermediate result that needs to get grouped by order ID. You get the dates by applying `MIN` or `MAX`.

```
SELECT
  order_number,
  MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'approve' THEN date END) AS approve_date,
  MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'cancel' THEN date END) AS cancel_date
FROM mytable
GROUP BY order_number
ORDER BY order_number;
```